# Mac like virtual desktop for windows while using dual monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I am thrilled to have multiple desktop/virtual desktops to keep my workspace organized and at the same time, I am using dual monitors to make my work more productive (at least I am thinking).

What I experience with Windows is when we connect to the dual monitors and when we switch between multiple desktops it always changes the desktop of both screens. But when I compare it with Mac if I want to change the desktop it will only change the desktop of the focused monitor and that was a lot easier when we work with dual monitors as extended settings. How can I get Mac behaviour on Windows?

I know I can get some windows available for all the desktops by `show this window on all desktops` settings but it does not allow customized desktops in each monitor. Does anyone know any solution for that?

Comment: Windows does not natively support this. You will need a different program that creates virtual desktops that natively supports this. Seeking software recommendations are off-topic however. You can try software-reqs stack exchange.